# How can I add custom scripts in index.html's head part in Docusaurus V2?

Tags: javascript, react-helmet, docusaurus

We are making a website with Docusaurus V2.

In Docusaurus V1, there is a `scripts` setting in `siteConfig.js` to cusutimize html's head content. But, I cannot find the corresponding setting in Docusaurus V2.

According to https://docusaurus.io/blog/2018/09/11/Towards-Docusaurus-2#layout, it seems possible to customize html's `<head>` part in V2.

> Layout
>
> The current state of Docusaurus is that it is in charge of the
>   entire layout and styling, unintentionally making it very hard for
>   users to customize their site's appearance to their wishes.
>
> For Docusaurus 2, layout and styling should be controlled by the user.
>   Docusaurus will handle the content generation, routing, translation,
>   and versioning. Inspired by create-react-app and VuePress, Docusaurus
>   will still provide a default theme, which the user can eject from, for
>   further layout and styling customization. This means that it is very
>   possible for the user to even change the HTML meta by using React
>   Helmet. Community-based themes are also very possible. This approach
>   of allowing users to be in charge of layout and styling is taken by
>   most static site generators.

I tried to use `react-helmet` in `src/pages/index.js`, with the following code:

```
function Home() {
  const context = useDocusaurusContext();
  const { siteConfig = {} } = context;
  return (
    <Layout
      title={`Hello from ${siteConfig.title}`}
      description="Description will go into a meta tag in <head />">
      <Helmet>
        <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>
      </Helmet>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

}

But the script `https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js` did not show up inside `<head></head>`

Has anyone encountered similar problem and could anyone give some help?

Answer (score 13):

Easier way:

Create a file /static/js/loadtags.js. Put your tags in there, like:

```
UST_CT = [];UST = { s: Date.now(), addTag: function(tag) { UST_CT.push(tag) } };UST.addEvent = UST.addTag;
```

Now update the scripts section in docusaurus.config.js

```js
  scripts: [
    
    {
      src:
        '/js/loadtags.js',
      async: false,
    },
    {
      src:
        'https://improve.attrace.com/server/ust.min.js?v=4.3.2',
      async: true,
    },
  ],
```

Comment: Just a tip in case you add this and it doesn't work. In my environment, it was required that I stop and restart yarn to get the new scripts item to take effect. If that doesnt work, try `yarn clear`

Answer (score 12):

Instead of React Helmet, use `'@docusaurus/Head'` instead.

```
import Head from '@docusaurus/Head';

function Home() {
  const context = useDocusaurusContext();
  const { siteConfig = {} } = context;
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Head>
        <script src="..."></script>
      </Head>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

We're working on this feature so you can add this via `docusaurus.config.js`. You can follow this PR to track the progress: https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/pull/1831.

We'll release `v2.0.0-alpha.27` soon so that you can try it out. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Which file this goes to?

Answer (score 1):

i am also developing a blog which is based on docusaurus.
and it provides the functionality to add script in head tag.
follow below steps :
1. Open siteConfig.js
2. // Add custom scripts here that would be placed in  tags.
  scripts: ['https://buttons.github.io/buttons.js'],

Comment: This is for Docusaurus 1, the question is about Docusaurus 2

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add custom scripts like analytics, tracking code, or any other third-party script to your Docusaurus site, you can achieve this by creating a dedicated JavaScript file in your project and updating your Docusaurus configuration. Here's how to do it:

### Step 1: Create a New JavaScript File

Firstly, create a new JavaScript file in the root of your Docusaurus project or any other suitable location. Name it appropriately; for example, if you're adding a Clarity analytics script, you might name it `_clarity.js`.

Inside this file, write your script logic. If your script needs to access the DOM, make sure to check if the DOM is available using Docusaurus's `ExecutionEnvironment`.

```js
import ExecutionEnvironment from '@docusaurus/ExecutionEnvironment';

if (ExecutionEnvironment.canUseDOM) {
    const clarityProjectId = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID';
  
    // Initialize or extend the global `clarity` function to queue commands
    window.clarity = window.clarity || function() {
      (window.clarity.q = window.clarity.q || []).push(arguments);
    };
  
    // Create the script element for the Clarity tracking code
    const clarityScript = document.createElement('script');
    clarityScript.src = `https://www.clarity.ms/tag/${clarityProjectId}`;
    clarityScript.async = true;
    clarityScript.defer = true;
  
    // Insert the script into the head of the document
    document.head.appendChild(clarityScript);
}
```

### Step 2: Update Docusaurus Configuration

Next, open your `docusaurus.config.js` file and update the `clientModules` section to include the path to your newly created JavaScript file:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ... existing config
  clientModules: [
    require.resolve('./_clarity.js'),
  ],
  // ... existing config
};
```

Hope this help in general.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if you solved this. Your friend is the Lifecycle API.

Specifically you want this:
https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/lifecycle-apis#injecthtmltags

Build a plugin and use the above. D2 is looking pretty strong, I wish they'd release a stable version 2 soon!