# Get a list of all pages from `docs` directory?

Tags: javascript, docusaurus

I am trying to implement a "Get random page" link in Docusaurus. For that I would like to get a list of all available pages/page ids+path from the docs/ directory.

Does Docusaurus have a way to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

I did not find any `native` or `plugin` way to achieve this... Here is how I you do it:

---

**PART 1**

Once you built you docusaurus website, will be generated a `sitemap.xml` file.
This file is locate at the root directory of your site and contains `all` of the url of the doc pages.

Create a `js` function that read this file and parse it. Then get a random `url` open it.

**TIP 1:** https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp

**TIP 2:** https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

---

**PART 2**

Then, you can embed your `JavaScript` using the `mdx` function of docusaurus.

**TIP:** [How can I add custom scripts in index.html's head part in Docusaurus V2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57859350/how-can-i-add-custom-scripts-in-index-htmls-head-part-in-docusaurus-v2)